# Getting formatted traceback when overwriting sys.excepthook

Tags: python, exception, logging, error-handling, unhandled-exception

I am rewording this question, as it seems I had some issues in my initial question and it was too vague.

I am working on trying to build a replacement function for sys.excepthook to save errors to file when running a batch job. I have referenced several sources and and am specifically having trouble getting the traceback to print to file. Below is something that is working for me.

```
import sys
import traceback
def saveError(exctype, value, tb):
    filename = tb.tb_frame.f_code.co_filename
    name = tb.tb_frame.f_code.co_name
    line_no = tb.tb_linno
    with open('filepath.txt','w', newline = '') as f:
        f.write(f"{filename}")
        f.write(f"{name}")
        f.write(f"{line_no}")
        f.write(f"{exctype.__name__}")
        f.write(f"{value}")
    f.close()

sys.excepthook = saveError

print(1/0)
```

The problem I'm running into is trying to print the full traceback, you can see above I've pulled out individual pieces of it but haven't been able to get the whole thing. A few examples of things I've tried below.

```
import traceback
trace = f"{traceback.format_exc()}"
```

This returns NoneType: None

```
f.write(f"{tb}")
```

This returns <traceback object at 0x7....

```
trace2 = traceback.format_tb(tb)
```

This seems to return nothing

Is there a way to get the traceback information into a string format and save it to file?

Comment: Well I posted one attempt above, but yes I can go back and try to get my previous versions too I suppose. You want to see all attempts I've made at making this work?

Comment: Have you verified that you can print *something* (not necessarily related to the exception) to this file?  And where do you *close* this file?

Comment: Yes, I added another version where I verify that I'm able to write some text to the file.

Answer (score 1):

A traceback object doesn't have those methods. You need to `import traceback` and then `traceback.print_exc(...)` etc.

Comment: Well this is definitely an obvious mistake I was making, but I still seem unable to get any information besides print_exc to say "none type". when I import that package and change the tb to traceback.